# Installing a forked github gem of Toto

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, github, rubygems

Ok, this is probably simple, but I'm having a bit of a pain trying to get it to work.

So I was using the gem "Toto", which I installed using "sudo gem install toto", but I recently found a fork of the gem I would rather use here https://github.com/evaryont/toto.

I tried specifying the gem url with --source, but I guess github doesn't support gems anymore aside from "[the list](http://gems.github.com/list.html)".  I then tried downloading the forked source and running "rake build" and "rake install" which seemed to create a gem just fine, but when I plug it back into the same application which comes with the gem, it fails to load.

It dies like this.

```
    computer:myblog User$ thin start -R config.ru
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- toto (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from config.ru:2
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from config.ru:1:in `new'
    from config.ru:1
```

Sample Toto Application

```
git clone git://github.com/cloudhead/dorothy.git myblog
```

I'm also a little discouraged about building the gem like this because I'm hosting on Heroku, and I would like to make sure that I can use this gem on there as well.  I suppose I may have to unpack this gem and commit it to my source?

---

### Update

I also tried using bundler with the following in my Gemfile, and I get the same error, would this mean its just an incompatibility in the sample code and the forked gem?

```
gem "toto", :git => "git://github.com/evaryont/toto.git"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running in a context where the gem exists? Bundler handles `:git`-installed gems by cloning the source and storing it in a special directory for bundled gems. It's not actually installed to your system, and won't run unless bundler is running first.

Try this:

```
bundle exec thin start -R config.ru
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to be working as far as I can tell, except it looks like it still using the old gem (even though I uninstalled it).  However I think thats just a code issue not working correctly at this time.  I'll accept the answer once I know for sure.